# Vault error when trying to manual unseal in a HA config: no expected answer for the server id provided

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to setup an HA cluster for Vault and I am stuck with some errors that I cannot solve. I have already searched online a lot and tested various solutions but I cannot make this work and I am going crazy.

I am trying to spawn a Vault cluster the most simple way possible. Everything is manual, no auto join, no auto unseal. My test setup is: 3 VMs with Docker engine in it, with one Vault instance running in each machine.

My procedure is this:

1. Run a docker container with Vault in Machine 1 (IP: 10.20.110.50). The `vault.json` configuration is locally saved in that machine, also a `vault-data` volume is created locally.
2. Init Vault, save token and keys. Unseal the Vault.
3. Run a docker container with Vault in Machine 2 (10.20.110.100) and execute `vault operator join http://10.20.110.50:8200`, get a response joined: true.
4. Run a docker container with Vault in Machine 3 (10.20.110.150) and execute `vault operator join http://10.20.110.50:8200`, get a response joined: true.

At this point I can see the Vault cluster in the UI and also with the list-peers command. The 2 and 3 instance are followers, instance 1 is leader. **Instance 2 and 3 are non voters though!**

Then, I try to manually unseal one of the followers instances with vault operator unseal , where key is the one generated by instance one. Here I get the error:

```
Error unsealing: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal
Code: 500. Errors:

* Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://10.20.110.50:8200/v1/sys/storage/raft/bootstrap/answer
Code: 400. Errors:

* no expected answer for the server id provided
```

What I see in the leader logs is also:

```
2024-01-16T10:18:21.563Z [ERROR] storage.raft: failed to appendEntries to: peer="{Nonvoter 0bff0048-5c43-c93c-b8a3-443ce621bf2c 10.20.110.150:8201}" error="dial tcp 10.20.110.150:8201: connect: connection refused"
```

These logs are printed continuosly because the leader is trying to connect to the peers.
I have also tested the connection between nodes:

Ping is working, the nodes are reachable.
All nodes can connect to port 8200 between each other.
Connection to port 8201 succeeds only if I am connecting to the leader. If I try to connect to port 8201 of Machine 2 and 3 I get connection refused.
The strange thing is that if I try to connect to port 8201 from withing the container (so 127.0.0.1:8201) it works. But I have investigated and this seems like it is normal. I will get connection refused until the Vaul is unsealed. And this is why the Machine 1 is the only one that I can connect to.
I have no firewall enabled.

My configs:

vault.json:

```
{
  "storage": {
    "raft": {
      "path": "/opt/vault/data/raft"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp": {
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "cluster_address": "0.0.0.0:8201",
      "tls_disable": true
    }
  },
  "telemetry": {
    "unauthenticated_metrics_access": true
  },
  "cluster_name": "vc",
  "api_addr": "http://{{HOST}}:8200",
  "cluster_addr": "https://{{HOST}}:8201",
  "ui": true,
  "disable_mlock": true,
  "log_level": "debug",
  "default_lease_ttl": "168h",
  "max_lease_ttl": "0h"
}
```

This configuration is copied locally to each server.
HOST is the IP of my machines that are hosting the Vault instances. So if the config is into the 10.20.110.50 server, the HOST value will be 10.20.110.50.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  vault:
    image: hashicorp/vault:1.15.2
    container_name: vault
    hostname: vault
    entrypoint: [ "vault", "server", "-config=/vault/config/vault.json" ]
    volumes:
      - vault-data:/opt/vault/data/raft
      - /home/root/vault/vault.json:/vault/config/vault.json:ro
    environment:
      - VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
    networks: 
      - vault-network  
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
      - 8201:8201
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider", "--tries=1", "http://127.0.0.1:8200"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 5s
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK

networks:
  vault-network:
    name: vault-network

volumes:
  vault-data:
    name: vault-data
    driver: local
```

This docker-compose is run locally on each server to spawn one single instance of Vault in each.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

The errors that you're seeing, both the:

```
* no expected answer for the server id provided
```

And the:

```
2024-01-16T10:18:21.563Z [ERROR] storage.raft: failed to appendEntries to: peer="{Nonvoter 0bff0048-5c43-c93c-b8a3-443ce621bf2c 10.20.110.150:8201}" error="dial tcp 10.20.110.150:8201: connect: connection refused"
```

Are very commonly associated with network connectivity issues amongst members of the Raft cluster.

My hunch is that this has something to do with Docker networking intricacies.  For example, in your docker-compose denotes a hostname that differs from what you are configuring in your Vault config:

```
<snip>
    container_name: vault
    hostname: vault
<snip>
```

Also, as a quick note, you are correct that testing connectivity on the cluster port (`8201`) using a utility like `nc` won't work until the cluster is unsealed and actively listening on that port.

I would take another look at how you're configuring your hostnames at the container level and make sure it jives with how you're setting up the `api_addr` and `cluster_addr` values in your Vault config.

Finally, I'll share with you a script I've created that creates a 2-node Raft cluster using Docker running on a singular machine (hence the ports that have been slightly updated to avoid port-conflicts).  Note that this does use enterprise Vault so you may need to change up the script slightly to make it work for non-enterprise.

```bash
# Create a Docker network so our containers can chat
docker network create vault-net

# Spin up 2 Vault servers in Docker
# Note that each set of server params maps to a variable, e.g.
#  vault-1 -> $server
#  8200    -> $api_port
#  8201    -> $cluster_port
for server_params in "vault-1,8200,8201" "vault-2,8210,8211"
do
  IFS="," read server api_port cluster_port <<< "$server_params"
  # Delete the server so we can recreate it
  docker rm -f $server
  # Delete the config directory so we can recreate it
  rm -rf $server
  # Create a directory where we will store our config and raft files
  mkdir -p $server/config $server/file
  # Write our license out
  echo $VAULT_LICENSE > $server/config/license.hclic
  # Create a config file
  tee $server/config/vault.hcl << EOF
ui            = true
license_path  = "/vault/config/license.hclic"
listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:$api_port"
  tls_disable = "true"
}
storage "raft" {
  path = "/vault/file"
  node_id = "$server"
}
api_addr     = "http://$server:$api_port"
cluster_addr = "https://$server:$cluster_port"
EOF

  docker run \
    --cap-add=IPC_LOCK \
    -e VAULT_ADDR='http://0.0.0.0:$api_port' \
    -p $api_port:$api_port \
    --name $server \
    --detach \
    --network vault-net \
    -v `pwd`/$server/config:/vault/config \
    -v `pwd`/$server/file:/vault/file \
    hashicorp/vault-enterprise server
done

sleep 15

# Initialize our leader node
export VAULT_ADDR=http://localhost:8200
vault operator init \
  -key-shares=1 \
  -key-threshold=1 \
  -format=json > init.json

# Unseal our leader node
export ROOT_TOKEN=$(cat init.json | jq -r .root_token)
export UNSEAL_KEY=$(cat init.json | jq -r '.unseal_keys_b64[0]')
vault operator unseal $UNSEAL_KEY
vault login $ROOT_TOKEN

# Unseal our follower node
export VAULT_ADDR=http://localhost:8210
vault operator raft join http://vault-1:8200
vault operator unseal $UNSEAL_KEY
sleep 2

# Check our cluster membership
vault operator raft list-peers
```

> Note how each of my containers has a unique name and I'm using that name when configuring my `api_addr` and `cluster_addr` config values.